# How to restrict 3 numbers before decimal and 2 numbers after decimal using angular8

Tags: angular, decimal

Hi I am working on angular8 and here i have to restrict input field for 3,2. it should allow upto 3 numbers before decimal and 2 numbers after decimal. i have used regex as well but didnt work.

```
pattern="/^\d{0,3}(?:\.\d{0,2})?/" and tried with directive as well, here in directive it takes upto 5 numbers limit including and excluding decimal, if decimal is entered before crossing 5 digits then it allows to enter 1 decimal value.
```

HTML:

```
<input type="textbox" [(ngModel)]="InputValue" placeholder="XX.XX" appTwoDigitDecimaNumber>
```

Directive:
[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/limit-two-digit-decimal-place-m6euve?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftwo-digit-decima-number.directive.ts)

```
 private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^\d*\.?\d{0,2}$/g);
  private specialKeys: Array<string> = ['Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', '-', 'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight', 'Del', 'Delete'];

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  }
  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log(this.el.nativeElement.value);
    if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
      return;
    }
    let current: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    const position = this.el.nativeElement.selectionStart;
    const next: string = [current.slice(0, position), event.key == 'Decimal' ? '.' : event.key, current.slice(position)].join('');
    if (next && !String(next).match(this.regex)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

Decimal Diretive:

```
 @Input() curValue:any;
  @Input() set maxDigits(maxDigits: number) {this.setRegex(maxDigits);} 
  private regexString(max?: number) {
    const maxStr = max ? `{0,${max}}` : `+`;
    return `^(\\d${maxStr}(\\.\\d{0,2})?|\\.\\d{0,2})$`
  }
  private digitRegex: RegExp;
  private setRegex(maxDigits?: number) {this.digitRegex = new RegExp(this.regexString(maxDigits), 'g')}
  private lastValid = '';
  private saved = "";
  private history = [];
  private default = '';
  private el: HTMLInputElement;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    this.el = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
    this.setRegex();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.default = this.curValue;
  }

  @HostListener("focus", ["$event.target.value"])
  onFocus(value) {
    this.el.value = value.replace(/[^0-9.]+/g, '');
    this.el.select();
  }

  @HostListener("blur", ["$event.target.value"])

  @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
  onInput(event) {
    const cleanValue = (event.target.value.match(this.digitRegex) || []).join('');
    if (cleanValue || !event.target.value){
      if(cleanValue != '' && this.history[this.history.length-1] == '' && this.saved != ""){
        this.history.push(this.saved);
        this.saved = '';
      }
      if(cleanValue == '' && this.history[this.history.length-1] != ''){
        this.history.push('');
      }
      this.lastValid = cleanValue
    }
    this.el.value = cleanValue || this.lastValid;
  }

  @HostListener("keyup.enter", ["$event.target.value"])
  onEnter(value) {
    this.saved = value;
  }

  @HostListener("keyup.control.z", ["$event.target.value"])
  onUndo(value) {
    if(this.history.length>0){
      this.lastValid = this.history.pop();
      this.el.value = this.lastValid;
    } else{
      this.lastValid = this.default;
      this.el.value = this.default;
    }
  }
```

1. Is there anyway to restrict from 1-100% of values?

Comment: `/^\d{0,3}(\.\d{0,2})?$/g` this regex worked for me with your problem

Comment: Thanks for response, but this is not working for me